# Python 2.7.12 not compatible with Django but still cannot be updated

Tags: arcmap, django

I have installed Python 3.6.4 on my computer. I am trying to set up Django but each time I try to use the command prompt, it tells me that the Python version am using is not compatible. When I check the Python version, it is Python 2.7.12. I haven't installed the latter but am wondering where it is coming from. I have deleted the Python27 folder but now my ArcMap is not working. How can I make the Python version 3.6.4 the one I'm using and still make my ArcMap work properly? I'm using Windows 7

Comment: ArcGIS ***requires*** the Python that it installs to function. You can have any Python you want for ArcPy use, so long as it's the Python installed with ArcGIS. You can have any number of Python builds installed, so long as you manage your PATH correctly. Removing installation directories corrupts the registry -- Please do not do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've put yourself into a bad state by simply removing the Python directory like that. Your best chance to get everything working as you want will involve tearing it all down and building it back up. NOT trying to fix what you've done.

I'd:

- remove Python 3.x
- remove ArcMap

Then, in this order:

- Install ArcMap
- Install Python 3.x
- pip install Django

Typically, the last Python installed on the machine becomes the one you get when you goto prompt and type `python`.